# Python: Apply Time series to each column of a dataframe and return a new row

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, multiple-columns, apply

```
DATE COL1 COL2
28/10/18 10 10
29/10/18 10 10
30/10/18 10 10
```

I have data in above format. I want to predict the value of COL1 and COL2 for date 31/10/2018 using the ARIMA model in python.

Is there a way I can apply the model to run on whole data frame and get the result as a row

```
DATE COL1 COL2
31/10/18 10 10
```

and then append the value at the end. Or the only way possible is going iteratively in the columns and running the time series model

```
DATE COL1 COL2
28/10/18 10 10
29/10/18 10 10
30/10/18 10 10
31/10/18 10 10
```

Comment: Can you add the code necessary to run the ARIMA model and get the result?

Comment: @kull1n I am not able to get your question. Do you want me to provide the code for arima model?

Comment: Yes to understand the data format of the output of the model and the necessary inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

create a function that uses the ARIMA model and return only the data you want.

There are two ways:

```
#applies to the entire data frame (0 = index and 1 = columns)
df2 = df.apply(function, axis=1)

#applies only to the series
df2 = df['date'].apply(function)
```

having the results, you can already organize data
learn more https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html